# Screenshot of entire webpage (localhost)

Tags: webpage-screenshot

I'm having a HTML file on my localhost and I want a screenshot of the entire page. Does anyone know some software that screenshots the entire page (localhost)? I found some plugins but they don't support localhost files.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, don't know why no one has responded your question yet :/

Comment: check this method: https://superuser.com/a/763832/1127431

Answer (score 3):

Press “PrtSc” on Windows or “Command+Shift+3/4” on Mac will just take screenshots of visible parts on the screen. To take a screenshot of an entire page, you can make use of some screenshot extensions. For Safari, [Awesome Screenshot](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.diigo.safari.awesomeScreenshot-5DXNM3K2CT) is a good choice. For Chrome, there are multiple [snapshot extensions](http://screenshot.net/chrome-extension-snapshot.html), such as Nimbus, Webpage Screenshot, Diigo and so on. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plugins or extensions such as Awesome Screenshot (Chrome), you need to access the local website from a local environment (Recommended: WAMP for Windows, MAMP for Mac and Xamp for Linux).

If you access the local website directly, you won't be able to take a whole screenshot. This is probably because the plugins or extensions do a request that cannot be answered without an environment.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's too late to reply, yet for those who are looking up,

Firefox browser has inbuilt screenshot option, Rightclick on the webpage, there is option for taking a section or full webpage.

For chrome or safari you can check out extensions like FullPageCapture etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your on a Mac just hit Command shift 4 and take as many screenshots as you want

Comment: I'm not that dumb .. Like I stated above; "I want a screenshot of the entire page". So the entire page,not the visible part. Anyway, I found a Chrome plugin called "Webpage screenshot" and it does the job. (also locally)

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows:**

Press the 'Print Screen' key on the upper right of your keyboard.

**For Mac**

For a drag screenshot

```
command + Shift + 4
```

For just a window's contents

```
command + Shift + 4 then spacebar
```

**For Linux**

Check accessories if your distro supports it

Comment: I'm not that dumb .. Like I stated above; "I want a screenshot of the entire page". So the entire page,not the visible part. Anyway, I found a Chrome plugin called "Webpage screenshot" and it does the job. (also locally)

Answer (score 0):

Install "Screen Capture (by Google)" - extension. It works fine for live websites. But when it comes to localhost, for some reason it doesn't work.
So, I found that if you install the same extension on Microsoft edge based on chromium engine, it works fine for localhost HTML5 files.